# how to pass data to function jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm try pass a parameter to a Jquery function using data property.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
<ul class="flexisel" data-visible-items="2">
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>

</ul>
```

I think this is the correctly way to pass parameter. But It doesn't work.

```
$(".flexisel").flexisel({
        clone: true,
        visibleItems: $(this).attr("data-visible-items") //This doesn't work
});
```

This sample works perfectly:

```
$(".flexisel").each(function () {
      //works       
      console.log("here", $(this).attr("data-visible-items"));
});
```

Comment: Data attributes should be accessed by $(this).data("visible-items")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first JavaScript snippet [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) doesn't refer to the collection as object literals (`{}`) do not create a new scope. In your second snippet `this` refers to the current element of the iteration as jQuery binds the `this` value of the handler using the current element of iteration, so you can code:

```
$(".flexisel").each(function() {
   $(this).flexisel({
        clone: true,
        visibleItems: $(this).data("visible-items")
   });
});
```